# How to substitute LEFT OUTER JOIN in JPQL if ON-CLAUSE is not allowed?

Tags: mysql, sql, openjpa, outer-join

I have quite sophisticated SQL query converted to JPQL.  Suddenly, I found that because I am on the version of OPENJPA 1.2.8 prior to 2.0, the ON-Clause does not work.  So, most probably I cannot use Left Open Join. What can be the best strategy in this case?

The JPQL query:

```
select priceListTerm.SELLING_PRICE, priceListTerm.COMMISSION_FORMAT, priceListTerm.COMMISSION,  
priceListAssignment.EFF_START_DATE, priceListAssignment.EFF_END_DATE, 
priceListAssignment.PRIORITY_LEVEL, 
venue.CODE, tb.HEADQUARTERS, vendor.NAME from PriceListTerm priceListTerm
JOIN PriceList priceList on priceListTerm.PRICELIST_UID = priceList.UIDPK
JOIN ProductSku productsku on priceListTerm.PRODUCTSKU_UID=productsku.UIDPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(PriceListAssignment priceListAssignment JOIN Venue venue on   
 priceListAssignment.VENUE_UID=venue.UIDPK
 JOIN Vendor vendor on vendor.UIDPK=venue.VENDOR_UID)
on priceListAssignment.PRICELIST_UID = priceList.uidpk
where productsku.skuCode= :sku 
and (vendor.name is null or vendor.name= :vendor)
order by priceListAssignment.PRIORITY_LEVEL;
```

Comment: The `ON` clause is standard ANSI SQL and has been for years. It'd be weird if that syntax wasn't supported. However, you could (probably) use `SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id` instead of `SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id`

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion is for inner join

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a native query. So the chunk of code that works is as follows:

```
...........
query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(GET_LOGICAL_SQL);

List<Object[]> list  = query.setParameter(1, skuCode).setParameter(2, vendorName).getResultList();

for (Object[] objects : list){
    BigDecimal sellingPrice = (BigDecimal)objects[0];
...........
```